# Como puedo leer un archivo JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json

Necesito sacar la información de este archivo pero no se como hacerlo ya soy algo novato con las consultas de este tipo JSON. 
y gracias por antemano

funcion que estoy usando:

```
        $source= file_get_contents('file_json.php'); 
$output = json_decode($source,true);

echo $output['resources']['data']['?'];
```

lo que quiero es saber esta linea pero no se como hacerlo

```
https://v.pinimg.com/videos/hls/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737.m3u8
```

aqui esta el codigo JSON :

```
{
"resources": {
    "fetching": {},
    "data": {
        "ddd": "si",
        "PinPageResource": {
            "field_set_key=\"detailed\",get_page_metadata=true,id=\"279012139395076462\",main_module_name=\"UnauthPinReactPage\",pure_react=true,python_resource_prefetch=false": {
                "status": "success",
                "message": "ok",
                "code": 0,
                "data": {
                    "origin_pinner": null,
                    "domain": "buzzfeed.com",
                    "done_by_me": false,
                    "edited_fields": ["description"],
                    "videos": {
                        "id": "4884525133403793441",
                        "video_list": {
                            "V_HLSV4": {
                                "url": "https://v.pinimg.com/videos/hls/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737.m3u8",
                                "width": 1080,
                                "duration": 74777.0,
                                "thumbnail": "https://i.pinimg.com/videos/thumbnails/originals/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737-00001.jpg",
                                "height": 1080
                            },
                            "V_HLSV3_MOBILE": {
                                "url": "https://v.pinimg.com/videos/v2/hls/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737_mobile.m3u8",
                                "width": 1080,
                                "duration": 74777.0,
                                "thumbnail": "https://i.pinimg.com/videos/thumbnails/originals/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737-00001.jpg",
                                "height": 1080
                            },
                            "V_HLSV3_WEB": {
                                "url": "https://v.pinimg.com/videos/v2/hls/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737_web.m3u8",
                                "width": 1080,
                                "duration": 74777.0,
                                "thumbnail": "https://i.pinimg.com/videos/thumbnails/originals/80/20/4d/80204d81a547d4df2b0c27bcbaf76737-00001.jpg",
                                "height": 1080
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "http_status": 200
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @gbianchi quiero obtener ese link del codigo pero no se como me puedes ayudar

Comment: Intentaste ya con un json_encode()...?

Comment: @Candelo no amigo porque no se nada de esto necesito algo de ayuda

Comment: En la última línea de código, cambia tu **echo $url_video['url'][1];** por un **echo json_encode($url_video['url'][1]);**
Y me dices que te sale

Comment: @Candelo puedes hacer una repuesta con la funcion completa por favor

Comment: Mira, en el mismo código que publicaste: "$PHP_data = file_get_contents('https://www.pinterest.com.mx/pin/279012139395076462/'); 
    preg_match('/,"data":(.+)/', $PHP_cUrl, $match);
    $url_video          = json_decode($match[1],1);
    echo $url_video['url'][1];"
Reemplaza esa última línea: **echo $url_video['url'][1];** por un **echo json_encode($url_video['url'][1]);**

Comment: @Candelo no funciona amigo no tienes otra idea

Comment: @sode que tiene la variable PHP_cUrl?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez fue un error de edion amigo listo ya esta bien

Comment: Si en vez de esa foto pones el json como texto podemos ayudarte mejor al menos hasta la parte donde sale la url que deseas extraer

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas lo que pasa es que no puedo poner mucho codigo amigo

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas deja busco otra forma

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas https://www.miblocdenotas.com/195701